# Why doesn't activate(ignoringOtherApps:) enable the menu bar?

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

There are a number of tutorials/questions/answers on StackOverflow about being able to launch a GUI application with a simple program, without creating an app bundle and Info.plist. The majority of these use the Objective-C method `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:true]` to bring the application to the foreground, along with `[NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:]` to bring the windows to the foreground.

The problem seems to be that on version 10.15 of macOS, the menu bar is not enabled until the first time you switch away from the app and back again. I've managed to reduce the problem to the following few lines of Swift:

```
// Run this, click on the Apple logo in the top left
// You cannot get the Apple system menu until you tab
// to another application and back again
import AppKit

var app = NSApplication.shared
app.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
app.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
app.run()
```

When this is run as a command line application, the Apple menu at the top left cannot be selected. If you switch from that app and then back again, it works.

Adding windows and doing the `makeKeyAndOrderFront` has no effect; you can add them in, and the window does get the focus - but the menu bar isn't enabled until you switch away/back.

What's also confusing is that if you make a directory `Example.app/Contents/MacOS` and then copy the above binary in, and use `open` to launch the app, then the menu does work right from first launch. The difference appears to be the way in which the app is launched from the Terminal vs LaunchServices.

Is there any way to fix this minimal example so that the menu works right away?

For ease of reproduction, I have pushed the code to https://github.com/alblue/Bugger and there's a makefile that will do the build and run it from the command line (`make run`) and via an app bundle (`make app`).

Comment: For your description, I believed that I had encountered this issue before. However, this issue only appears if your app starts from Xcode run command. If you archive the app and run it, the issue doesn't exist. Did you try to archive it and run it again?

Comment: The problem is I’ve got this as a minimal example of a problem which exists in a different environment, and it uses this mechanism to launch an app, so it’s not a case of using Xcode to build it. If is also the case that it used to work in older versions of macOS which is unfortunate.

Comment: If your purpose is to launch an app when macOS starts up, you can try [this sample](https://github.com/owenzhao/LoginItem-Sample) that I created. However, normally your app should be hidden and show in the menubar, instead of running in the foreground directly.

Comment: No, this isn’t about launching at start up (but thanks for the link). This is about being able to launch the app and come to the foreground; specifically, this is a bug seen when creating a launch from within an IDE (non xcode) and the minimal case is the result of it.

Comment: I didn't understand. If you want to launch an app from another app, you should use [launchApplication(at:options:configuration:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1534810-launchapplication#). The app you called would bring to foreground without any extra code.

Comment: Does that work without an .app directory and without an Info.plist as described?

Comment: You can try [launchApplication(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1531434-launchapplication#), which only requires the app name.

Comment: The problem isn’t how to launch another application though, it’s about how to have a self contained executable launched that displays a GUI. The application name doesn’t exist because it’s a standalone binary; there’s no Info.plist and therefore no app name. It’s not registered with LaunchServices so can’t be opened with (say) open -a. In the repository I’ve linked above it’s launched from a makefile for example. If the launchApplication can refer to a binary by path it might be possible to do but you stop couldn’t launch it from a male file. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I see. I think in your question, the first sentence "There are a number of tutorials/questions/answers on StackOverflow about being able to launch a GUI application from a simple program", should be changed to "within a simple program". The "from" here kept me thinking you wanted to launch an app from another.

Comment: Thanks Owen, have improved the question with your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Owen for raising this back up to my attention -- I managed to discover that by moving the call into the app delegate the problem is solved 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to discover a simple fix for this; move the activate into the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` delegate:

```
import AppKit

@objc
class Delegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
        func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
                app.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
                app.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
        }
}

var app = NSApplication.shared
let delegate = Delegate()
app.delegate = delegate
app.run()
```

After this change, the menu is clickable.

For 10.15, the call to `setActivationPolicy` also needs to be in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` callback.

Comment: I've uploaded this fix to the GitHub repository https://github.com/alblue/Bugger/commit/def736d6eb46df395ab8313a8d84446b0344b71c for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I switched these lines and then the menu bar worked as expected!

From:

```
NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
```

To:

```
NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
```